# Maximal Subgroups of Symmetric Gropus

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if someone can point me towards a resource that gives some information, possibly some lists, about maximal subgroups of symmetric groups. Wikipedia tells me that they fall into 3 classes but I haven't been able to find out anything more.

Comment: The alternating subgroup is of index 2, so that's certainly one case of maximal subgroups.

Answer (score 4):

See *Permutation Groups* by Dixon and Mortimer (p. 268).  The three classes are (paraphrasing from D&M):

1. Intransitive subset stabilisers isomorphic to $S_m\times S_{n-m}$, for some $m$ with $1\leq m <n/2$;
2. Stabilisers of a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into equal parts and isomorphic with $S_k\wr S_m$;
3. Either $A_n$ or a proper primitive subgroup.

While the subgroups of types 1 and 2 are all maximal, not all those of type 3 are maximal.  For the precise list of groups of type 3 that are maximal subgroups, see [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387902237) by Liebeck, Praeger and Saxl.